# What's the commended way/library to transform a Json?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a Web Service that returns the following Json:

```
[{"DailyHedge": "1.3414894654050926"}, 
 {"OptimalHedge": "1.6788094119827568"}]
```

and for the purpose of plotting it using d3js I need to transform it to:

```
[{"category": "DailyHedge", "measure": 1.3414894654050926}, 
 {"category": "OptimalHedge", "measure": 1.6788094119827568}]
```

I have been skimming over [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) but in general I am not sure about what to use for this ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with plain, vanilla JavaScript, but since you're using D3, this can be done with `d3.keys` and `d3.values`.

According to the API, [d3.keys](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#keys):

> Returns an array containing the property names of the specified object (an associative array). The order of the returned array is undefined.

And d3.values:

> Returns an array containing the property values of the specified object (an associative array). The order of the returned array is undefined.

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [{
  "DailyHedge": "1.3414894654050926"
}, {
  "OptimalHedge": "1.6788094119827568"
}];

var newData = [];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  newData.push({
    category: d3.keys(d)[0],
    measure: +d3.values(d)[0]
  });
});

console.log(newData)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

In vanilla JavaScript, just use `Object.keys` and `Object.values`. However, `Object.values` [doesn't work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) on IE, Opera or Safari. An alternative is using a `for...in` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Heres an implementation with plain javascript:

```
var data = [{"DailyHedge": "1.3414894654050926"},
 {"OptimalHedge": "1.6788094119827568"}];

var newdata = [];

for(let key in data)
{
    let obj = data[key];

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

        var row = {"category": key, "measure": obj[key]};

        newdata.push(row);

    });
}

console.log(newdata);
```